# Javascript, ¿Como crear acceso directo con chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

¡Buenas tardes! Estoy investigando hace un tiempo y no he encontrado nada al respecto, estoy desarrollando una web, y me interesa agregar una función para crear un acceso directo en moviles.

Para ser mas detallistas, si nosotros vamos a cualquier página web desde chrome en android, tenemos la opción de crear un acceso directo, que quedará en el escritorio. Al pulsarlo, nos abre la web. ¿Hay alguna manera de realizar esto pero con una función? Es decir, que cuando se abra la web, por ejemplo, automaticamente se haga una solicitud para agregar el sitio como un acceso directo?

Desde ya, muchas gracias. La web la estoy desarrollando con HTML, CSS y Javascript (Imagino que de ser posible, se hará desde js), pero no habría problema en incluir otra tecnología de ser necesaria. ¡Quedo al tanto!

Comment: Sinceramente, espero que no exista esa opción automática, no me gustaría que una web agregue contenido sin preguntarme. De hecho, tampoco me gusta que pregunte, odio entrar a una página y que aparezca solicitud para enviar notificaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo mas parecido que he visto es el acceso directo de las pwa, el instalador de las pwa, lo probé en localhost y me funcionó, para que funcione correctamente mira las condiciones:
Este link para los pasos de como crear una wpa y manejo de service worker:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers?hl=es

Esto es para poner el botón para el instalador, para este paso mira el link de arriba antes:

https://web.dev/codelab-make-installable/

Espero que te sirva un poco de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que no es posible hacer lo que dices.

Lo mas cercano seria hacer un popup con las instrucciones para hacerlo y mostrarlo al inicio de la aplicación.

Prueba esta librería: https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Te ayudará con lo que mencione del popup.